# Cómo subir Imagen a MySQL con PHP desde Alamofire en Swift

Tags: php, webservice, swift, alamofire

Estoy intentando subir una imagen a mi BBDD, el problema que tengo es que yo la quiero meter directamente en la BBDD de datos pero toda la documentación que encuentro es de poner la imagen en un archivo y en la BBDD la URL de la image.

¿Cómo puedo meter la imagen en una columna BLOB de mi Base de datos?

Este es el código Swift:

```
let imageData = Imagen1.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)
if(imageData == nil) { return }

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "Image1", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
}, to:"http://rrggrr.com/Arc/Form.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
            //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
            //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
        print(encodingError)
    }
}
```

Y este el PHP:

```
$Image1 = $_POST['Image1'];
$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error conexion con MySQL : " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Form1(Image1) value ('{$Image1}')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: en nuestro caso, donde estoy trabajando, a la hora de subir imágenes no hay "tanto problema" pero los videos siempre habíamos tenido problemas, por que se suele tornar muy lenta la subida, los data son muy grandes, y en caso de imágenes solíamos convertirlos a base 64 que la verdad es mucho peor.. así que usamos Firebase, ahí se suben los data muy rápido, tanto imágenes como videos, y las urls son las que se mandan a las API, y a la hora de hacer los request solamente estamos leyendo las url y se ven sin problemas

Comment: ¿Entonces el código PHP es el que se encarga de insertarlo a la BBDD? Supongo que lo que te falta es construir la llamada HTTP (en Swift) que inserte una imagen para que PHP la lea y la inserte en BBDD